# How to separate two boards joined by many folded jumper wires

Tags: pcb, jumper

I'm trying to fix an oven that is not heating. Based on voltage readings at the elements, I am highly suspicious of the relays. Apparently burnt relays or blown solder joints on the relays are a semi-common failure on oven power boards.

The problem, is that I've never seen two boards joined with dozens of jumper wires like the image below, see the long row of wires at the top that fold over the edge of the PCB to the lower board.

[image]

Not my image ([source](https://a-zapplianceparts.com/products/control-panel-60c21610110-00n21611302-p285-60-gg352)), but same board(s).

Is the idea to just bend the wires carefully (after dealing with the plastic spacer/lock pieces)?

Comment: Are the wires designed to bend? will gently heating them help?

Comment: They are all in a straight line, as if designed to hinge, and the board cutouts look designed to guide them and keep them apart. I wouldn't be surprised if the board was originally one piece, the connection wires were dispensed as 'components', and then the board was split and folded after soldering. Although the wires are individually thin and flexible, that many in parallel will require quite a bit of force to bend. Try to spread your force evenly along the board, to avoid stressing it too much. Heating will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts from me.

1. can I assume the heater elements are not OC.
2. This module type will tease open with care. Check the black relays, the most common to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so seems they were too cheap to buy proper connectors and ribbon cables then. It shouldn’t be too hard to fix though if you accidentally break one. Visual inspection for burnt solder points/burned relays, then check if those relays are normally open but are failed closed with DMM. Replace relays shouldn’t be expensive if you have the soldering iron and skill to desolder big parts. Also suggest you check for any obviously blown caps (Often bloated looking SMT part / failed short with DMM) as this is common in consumer products.

Good luck!